# Не работает редирект .htaccess

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, modx

Добрый день. Совершенно отчаялся настроить редирект на своём сайте, может быть, кто-нибудь сможет помочь.

Сайт на modx Evolution. Страница попала в индекс, после этого урл вручную изменили. Старый урл выдаёт 404 ошибку. Надо с него сделать редирект на новый урл. Перепробовал все варианты редиректов в .htaccess, которые смог найти за несколько недель. Ни один из них не работает, в лучшем случае выдаёт ошибку 500.

При этом файл .htaccess содержит много различных редиректов (friendly url, www, multilingual и другие), которые успешно работают.

```
Redirect /page.html http://site.ru/new-page.html
```

и подобные не работают.

Если есть время, помогите, пожалуйста.

Содержимое .htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks

```
# Friendly URLs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

# Redirect from mydomain.com/rootname to mydomain.com/rootname/
RewriteRule ^en$ en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ru$ ru/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|ru)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ru/$1 [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В основном htacces у modx выглядит так:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
#RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.org\.ua [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.org.ua/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Перед строчкой

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

ставьте свой редирект, он должен работать.

Comment: binliz, можно я покажу вам свой .htaccess и поможете мне вставить этот редирект?

Comment: надо было его сразу показать :) показывайте, конечно.

Comment: По ходу я ваш файл вижу, вы раньше в вопросах ставили, сообщите, что конкретно вы пытаетесь добавить, с какой ссылки на какую переход?

Comment: да, это он. Я его ещё раз добавил, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: со старой: http://site.ru/ru/about/news/17-ya-mezhdunarodnaya-vyistavka-oborudovaniya-mashin-i-ingredientov-dlya-pishhevoj-i-pererabatyivayushhej-promyishlennosti-agroprodmash-2012.html

на новую? http://www.site.ru/ru/about/news/17-ya-mezhdunarodnaya-vyistavka.html

Comment: RewriteRule ^en$ en/ [R=301,L]
вот эти строки указываю на переходы:
^ - начало строки от домена
$ - конец сторки
Данная функция делает редирект с просто en на en/ (со слешем).
R=301 это заголовко который надо отослать, а L что в данном случаи это последнее правило.

Если вы там по аналогии напишите свой переход он у вас будет замечательно работать.

Comment: RewriteRule ^ru/about/news/17-ya-mezhdunarodnaya-vyistavka-oborudovaniya-mashin-i-ingredientov-dlya-pishhevoj-i-pererabatyivayushhej-promyishlennosti-agroprodmash-2012.html ru/about/news/17-ya-mezhdunarodnaya-vyistavka.html [R=301,L]

Comment: Работает! Благодарю!)))
Наконец-то)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так усложнять.
Попробуйте компонент **Redirector**

> Redirector можно установить на свой
> сайт из админ.панели в разделе
> «Управление пакетами». После установки
> в меню админки в разделе «Компоненты»
> появляется новый пункт — «Управление
> редиректами». Заходим и видим пока еще
> пустой список редиректов.
>
> Нажимаем кнопку «Создать новый
> редирект» во всплывающем окне пишем
> правило:
>
> Шаблон — url старой страницы без
> первого слеша, например old-page.html
> Цель — полный адрес новой страницы
> http://new-domain.ru/new-page.html

Comment: Вы читать умеете? MODx EVO и REVO, разницу знаете? Есть и у evo свой компонент и плагин, но вопрос стоял именно так, как был решен.

Comment: Вас понял. Я почему то подумал о Revo ) не знаю что черт дернул ))

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду) Есть другой сайт, на Modx Revo. Вдруг пригодится)